# Adding active class to font awesome list items in angularJS

Tags: css, angularjs

What is the correct way to add a active class to a list items that is using font awesome icons? Im using ui.router and the ui-sref-active="active" to add the class but I can't seem to find the right way to add the css.

the HTML Is:

```
<nav id="sidebar2-pullout">
    <ul class="list-unstyled sidebar2-nav">
        <li><a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref="navHome">Home</a></li>
        <li><a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref="navEvaluation">Evaluations</a></li>
        <li><a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref="navQuestions">Questions</a></li>
        <li><a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref="navPrerequisites">Prerequisites</a></li>
        <li><a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref="navDocuments">Documents</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

and the css is

```
    ul.sidebar2-nav li a {
  color: #2A7FCE;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
}
ul.sidebar2-nav li a:hover {
  color: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
}
ul.sidebar2-nav li:before {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  content: '\f00c';
  margin:0 5px 0 -15px;
  color: #2A7FCE;
  background: white;
}
ul.sidebar2-nav li:before .active {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  content: '\f00c';
  margin:0 5px 0 -15px;
  color: #000;
  background: grey;
}
```

Comment: What triggers the active class?

Answer (score 1):

You would use the ng-class directive. It works like so

```
<li><a ui-sref-active="active" ng-class="{active: selectedListItem}" ui-sref="navDocuments">Documents</a></li>
```

Where "selectedListItem" is a property on the scope and set to true. Anything in that place which evaluates to true will cause active to be set as a class. If you set $scope.selectedListItem = false, the active class would be removed.

Here is an example where I have a property on the angular scope that I set to a string to indicate which item is active.

http://jsfiddle.net/JULxK/

On each item, the ng-class directive sets the class to active if the property matches the keyword for that item.

Usually when I do things like this, I like to generate my lists with an ng-repeat directive and have a $scope.selectedNavIndex.
On each item, I would put ng-class="{active: selectedNavIndex == $index}"

$index is a variable implicitly available inside an ng-repeat which equals the index of the repeated element. To change the active class from one item to another, you would simply set the $scope.selectedNavIndex = 3. You can do this from the controller or even with an ng-click="selectedNavIndex = $index"

Comment: Thank you!! Works perfectly now. I was missing just one piece of the puzzle

Comment: Glad I could help. Please accept my answer when you have a chance so I can get points. Thanks!